# Phonegap - does php work like html and css?

Tags: php, phonegap

Does php work in phonegap? I cannot find the answer.

I ask as javascript works for sure.

Thank you

Comment: PHP is a serverside technology and is not supported by Phonegap

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Short answer no.

```
Insert Code here
```

You should really look at improving your knowledge of language types first. Php is server side based.